# Pandas: Is it possible to create an Excel Slicer-like (interactive filters) within Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm planning on creating some pd.pivot_table() views with some sns.plots and export as a html report. Is it possible to have the data / graph update based on an user-friendly filter button?

For instance, I want the end users to have the ability to select their Sales Region, Direction of Trade (Export vs. Import), etc. and view the data/graph accordingly.

Comment: You may need to check TkInter or Dask or https://plot.ly/python/